Why was BABE Secondary Slot Assignment not implemented in a round-robin style?
The Polkadot documentation mentions that secondary slots in BABE use a round-robin style for block assignments. However, the secondary slots are not strictly assigned in a round-robin fashion, instead, they rely on randomness combined with the slot number to assign the secondary author.
Since secondary slots are predictable within an epoch (due to the randomness staying constant), I’m curious about the following:

Would implementing a round-robin system for secondary slots
introduce any potential security risks or other concerns?

Is there any specific reason or advantage for not using round-robin
in the current secondary slot assignment, despite it being mentioned
in the documentation?


Any insights into the reasoning behind this design choice would be very helpful!
Thanks in advance!


Not that I can think of, as you said, within an epoch secondary slot authors are predictable, so any potential for censoring applies in both cases.

I don't really remember the reasoning behind this, pretty sure it just boiled down to "because we wanted to". I went back to check and in the first commit implementing secondary slots I actually did the round-robin implementation like Aura (author_index = slot % number_of_authorities).


Indeed that documentation in the wiki is wrong, but the spec defines this correctly (https://spec.polkadot.network/sect-block-production#defn-babe-secondary-slots).
